# Expressing intervals between variables in a wide dataframe

Tags: r

I have a simple dataframe that looks like this:

```
  name sample1 sample2 sample3
  V01       1       2        3
  V02      10      20       30
  V03     100     200      300
```

created here:

```
DF <- data.frame(name=c("V01", "V02", "V03"), sample1=c(1,10,100), sample2=c(2,20,200), sample3=c(3,30,300))
```

I am trying to beat up this data frame to look as such:

```
  name   begin   end 
  V01        1     2
  V01        2     3
  V02       10    20
  V02       20    30
  V03      100   200
  V03      200   300
```

I reflexively looked towards `tidy` and `reshape2`, but I'm starting to realize I don't really need to simply reshape this dataframe, I need to find some way to express the interval between values. I feel like it is more of a timeseries problem than a reformatting issue. Or, it is more of a matter of performing some sort of differencing operation, then reformatting the results.

What is the best way to approach this kind of problem? Is there a way to solve this with `tidy` alone that I can't figure out?

Comment: by the way, is the number of columns small and fixed?

Answer (score 4):

Just subset and bind together?

```
DF1 <- DF[-4]
DF2 <- DF[-2]
colnames(DF1) <- colnames(DF2) <- c("name", "begin", "end")
rbind(DF1, DF2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just in case that number of columns is variable:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

d %>% 
  mutate(i=1:n()) %>% 
  gather(k, v, -name, -i) %>% 
  arrange(i) %>%
  mutate(begin=value, end=lead(value)) %>% 
  filter(variable!=names(d)[ncol(d)]) %>%
  select(name, begin, end)

#   name begin end
# 1  V01     1   2
# 2  V01     2   3
# 3  V02    10  20
# 4  V02    20  30
# 5  V03   100 200
# 6  V03   200 300
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you could get there just by creating two new datasets, one with column sample3 deleted, the other with sample1, and then combining them with rbind after renaming the columns.

I will write some code to do it, but I doubt I will finish before someone beats me too it (it is quite late here :)

Comment: Yeah, but writing code trumps prose. I was too slow.